# PCI Compliance: File Integrity Checkers

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, data-integrity

We're looking for a file integrity checker for our windows server environment. Anyone have any good suggestions?

Comment: Windows has a built in "Windows File Protection" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222193   Would this suffice?

Comment: I don't think PCI auditors would find that to be enough. It's only going to monitor certain Windows system files - none of your application or data files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen Tripwire highly recommended on UNIX platforms; I believe there is a Windows version as well, might be a starting point.

Comment: There is a windows version.

Comment: +1 - does what it says on the tin. Perfect for assisting with PCI compliance.

Comment: Another Tripwire/Windows customer here.  Do your homework beforehand to narrowly identify what files you want to track, and how you want to be alerted.  The product has so many features that you run the risk of "optional paralysis". Also the UI is a wee bit funky - you have to click on folders in odd ways that are hard to explain. It feels like a throwback to early 1990s X window managers, which just happens to be the time and place that tripwire dates from.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [Verisys](http://www.ionx.co.uk). Like Tripwire it does file integrity monitoring and has a central administration console for reporting etc, but it's a whole lot easier to use than the commercial versions of Tripwire, and cheaper too :)